# Creating a binary truth "table"

Tags: java

First time posting on here! So ive searched and searched and cant find an answer. I dont really need a table, just to have that kind of output such as
0 and 0 = 0,
0 and 1 = 1,
and so on...
I need to read from a file that will extract the numbers and they are 0 0..0 1..1 0..1 1
I need to then make the AND, OR, NAND, and NOR "table" for them.
I created an arrayList for them, so i can access them easier. the method i was going to do doesnt work and will take very long lines of code and pretty much be duplicated stuff. Im trying to think of a way to use a loop, but have mental block. can anyone help me please?
heres what im talking about the code i have

```
    int rec3a = Integer.parseInt(list1.get(2));
    int rec3b = Integer.parseInt(list1.get(3));
        System.out.println("AND:");
        if(rec3a == 0 && rec3b == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("0");
        }
        if(rec3a == 0 && rec3b == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("0");
        }
        if(rec3a == 1 && rec3b == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("0");
        }
        if(rec3a == 1 && rec3b == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("1");
        }
    }
```

this doesnt really work for the OR statement either..its just a giant mess lol..any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the bitwise operators,

```
int rec3a = 1;
int rec3b = 0;
// AND
System.out.println(rec3a & rec3b);
// OR
System.out.println(rec3a | rec3b);
// NAND
System.out.println((rec3a & rec3b) == 1 ? 0 : 1);
// NOR
System.out.println((rec3a | rec3b) == 1 ? 0 : 1);
```

Which (in this example) outputs

```
0
1
1
0
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!! i didnt know about this. how will i go about taking the opposite? for NAND and NOR? i tried doing ~(rec3a & rec3b) but it gives a -1

Comment: @user3216846 I added NAND and NOR to my answer using a ternary.

Comment: oh i didnt see that..sorry..thanks so much! now everything is running smoothly :)

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify this to:

```
    if (rec3a == 1 && rec3b == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("0");
    }
```

For the `OR` case it would be:

```
    if (rec3a == 1 || rec3b == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("0");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With Integers 0 and 1, you can use the built in [bit-wise operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

```
System.out.println(rec3a & rec3b); //AND
System.out.println(rec3A | rec3b); //OR
```